# trigram and prevtwomap feature generator in xml descriptor

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using OpenNLP NameFinder. It allows us to define feature generators for entities like this (taken from [here](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.featuregen)):

```
 <generators>
  <cache> 
    <generators>
      <window prevLength = "2" nextLength = "2">          
        <tokenclass/>
      </window>
      <window prevLength = "2" nextLength = "2">                
        <token/>
      </window>
      <definition/>
      <prevmap/>
      <bigram/>
      <sentence begin="true" end="false"/>
    </generators>
  </cache> 
</generators>
```

But I am unable to find XML feature generator for TrigramFeatureGenerator and PrevTwoMapFeatureGenerator. I tried  and  but it showing InvalidFormatException. Can anyone tell me xml descriptor for Trigram and PrevTwoMap feature generator?

Comment: Can you let me know how did you read this XML using NameFinder Java API.

Comment: read xml file as any other file and convert it into byte array, then pass byte array into api.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any standard xml descriptor for **TrigramNameFeatureGenertor** and **PreviousTwoMapFeatureGenerator** but I figured out a way. I registered **trigram** and **prevtwomap** as custom xml descriptor which points to their respective java classes.